# How to sort by "connected" fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm not sure how to phrase it, but I'd like to sort the following data in a way that the child messages are immediately below their parents.

```
{ "_id" : "oI", "msg" : "Hello", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:01:43.749Z") },
{ "_id" : "z", "msg" : "can you hear me?", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:01:46.569Z"), "tcount" : 3 },
{ "_id" : "wG", "msg" : "Undsen bichver 2", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:00:58.254Z") },
{ "_id" : "BF", "msg" : "Undsen bichver 3", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:06.784Z") },
{ "_id" : "Jq", "msg" : "Undsen bichver 4", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:11.785Z") },
{ "_id" : "oP", "parentId" : "z", "msg" : "Test 1", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:02:06.860Z") },
{ "_id" : "Mq", "parentId" : "z", "msg" : "Test 2", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:05:37.173Z") },
{ "_id" : "Lq", "parentId" : "z", "msg" : "Test 3", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:24.370Z") }
```

The sort I used to display the above result is this:

```
.sort({ "parentId": 1, "ts": 1 })
```

The result I want is this:

```
{ "_id" : "oI", "msg" : "Hello", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:01:43.749Z") },
{ "_id" : "z", "msg" : "can you hear me?", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:01:46.569Z"), "tcount" : 3 },
{ "_id" : "oP", "parentId" : "z", "msg" : "Test 1", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:02:06.860Z") },
{ "_id" : "Mq", "parentId" : "z", "msg" : "Test 2", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T01:05:37.173Z") },
{ "_id" : "Lq", "parentId" : "z", "msg" : "Test 3", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:24.370Z") },
{ "_id" : "wG", "msg" : "Undsen bichver 2", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:00:58.254Z") },
{ "_id" : "BF", "msg" : "Undsen bichver 3", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:06.784Z") },
{ "_id" : "Jq", "msg" : "Undsen bichver 4", "ts" : ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:11.785Z") }
```

Note the records with `"parentId" : "z"` are immediately below its parent (`"_id" : "z"`)

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: @buræquete, I strictly need it like the above example so I don't have to touch the application logic.

Comment: I see, sorry for my assumption there... I updated my answer with a perfect solution! Can you check it?

Comment: Thanks, @buræquete, gonna let you know when I check it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) to create new field you can then sort by:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            sortBy: { $ifNull: [ "$parentId", "$_id" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            sortBy: -1, parentId: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dBRvjmw7PTw)

Comment: Nice. But how to order it with `ts` without breaking the "parent-children" connection? Tried to add `ts: 1` on `$sort`. But that's not giving the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve your desired sorting with the following;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "parentId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "parent"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      fake_ts: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [ { $size: "$parent" }, 1 ] },
          then: "$parent.ts",
          else: "$ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { 
      fake_ts: 1,
      ts: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      fake_ts: 0,
      parent: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Where I first [join](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with itself to get parent within each child document, then I [create a dummy field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) (idea from @mickl), and use parent's `ts` for child documents. Then I just [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) & [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) out temp fields.

Sorting is done with first `fake_ts`, then with `ts`, so that we will get the child documents always under the parent, but they will be sorted with their own `ts` between themselves.

The result will be;

```
[
  {
    "_id": "oI",
    "msg": "Hello",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T01:01:43.749Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "z",
    "msg": "can you hear me?",
    "tcount": 3,
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T01:01:46.569Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "oP",
    "msg": "Test 1",
    "parentId": "z",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T01:02:06.86Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "Mq",
    "msg": "Test 2",
    "parentId": "z",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T01:05:37.173Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "Lq",
    "msg": "Test 3",
    "parentId": "z",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:24.37Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "wG",
    "msg": "Undsen bichver 2",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T02:00:58.254Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "BF",
    "msg": "Undsen bichver 3",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:06.784Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": "Jq",
    "msg": "Undsen bichver 4",
    "ts": ISODate("2019-09-20T02:01:11.785Z")
  }
]
```

Check the code interactively on [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q7zQQshRLdy)